# googleusercontent.com took too long to respond

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Everything was working fine, but Suddenly, this error pops up whenever i tries to open my vertex AI's workbench notebooks in jupyterlab. Even the side walkthrough menu stopped working with the same error.
[image: error message when i notebook in jupyter-lab]
[image: walkthrough not working for similar error]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I needed to restart my router, and the issue was solved!